# MailForm gem not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a basic email form set up using the MailForm gem, but I can't get it to actually deliver emails, even when creating a new message in the console.

I'm using Amazon's SES service for emails, and they are working fine for things like Devise confirmation messages, so it seems like that is working. The output from the console looks like it's successfully sending as well but it never comes through.

### Model

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base

    attribute :name,      :validate => true
    attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
    attribute :file,      :attachment => true

    attribute :message
    # attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

    # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
    # in ActionMailer accepts.
    def headers
      {
        :subject => "My Contact Form",
        :to => "myemailaddress@gmail.com",
        :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
      }
    end
end
```

### Console

```
irb(main):001:0> c = Contact.new
=> #<Contact:0x007fe587c1c0b8>
irb(main):002:0> c.email = "hello@goodbye.com"
=> "hello@goodbye.com"
irb(main):003:0> c.name = "It's my name"
=> "It's my name"
irb(main):004:0> c.message = "No subject"
=> "No subject"
irb(main):005:0> c.deliver
```

### Console Output

```
MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 29.8ms

Sent mail to myemailaddress@gmail.com (285.5ms)
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 00:17:49 -0400
From: It's my name <hello@goodbye.com>
To: myemailaddress@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5409396d8fe66_14dda3ff2c180c46c84468@Chriss-Macbook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: My Contact Form
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h4 style="text-decoration:underline">My Contact Form</h4>


  <p><b>Name:</b>
  It&#39;s my name</p>

  <p><b>Email:</b>
  hello@goodbye.com</p>

  <p><b>Message:</b>
  No subject</p>


=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I'm using Amazon's SES for email, which requires that you prove you have access to the email address before it will send messages from it.  That means that that the "send" field cannot be the email address of the person submitting the form, it must be a vetted email address.